# How to getting data from Excel or PDF or Word in Asp.net 2010 using RADGrid Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, telerik

i am getting error when i upload RADGrid Control on server it run properly but when i export data into PDF or Word or Excel, not display data only display html tags like this

```
<span class=highlight></span>M<span class=highlight></span>M<span class=highlight></span>/<span class=highlight></span>P<span class=highlight></span>I<span class=highlight></span>/<span class=highlight></span>G<span class=highlight></span>U<span class=highlight></span>D<span class=highlight></span>M<span class=highlight></span>/<span class=highlight></span>8<span class=highlight></span>
```

I'm using code like this:

```
 protected void ExportToPdf_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
    }
    protected void ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();

    }
    protected void ExportToWord_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();
}
```

Comment: if possible then please provide more information / your page code.
and which type of data you bind into grid.

Comment: it is direct control that provided by Telerik RadGrid Control which we can use in our application with some modification code

Comment: Please check below link for reference.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx
there is not any such type issue with RadGrid but if you still have issue then after your export statement again bind your grid or use Advance data binding.

Answer (score 0):

i attached one sample image where you can check your exported pdf's html.
please check and let me know if any concern.
[image]